# I tried installing k6 on Mac but it did not work

Tags: performance, testing, automated-tests, load, k6

I tried installing k6 (load test) on Mac based on the documentation: https://k6.io/docs/getting-started/installation/#macos

`brew install k6` but I get the error:

```
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I tried `brew install grafana/k6` but it also resulted in same error.

I wanted to install it directly instead of using docker.